# Drupal 8: how to link a facet to a custom facet processor module

Tags: facet

I've found some guidance on creating a custom facet module in Drupal 8; however, they skip instructions on how to link the facet to the custom processor.

http://tech.dichtlog.nl/facets/2015/11/30/facets-processor.html

Just writes, "Apply the processor to the facet"

Elsewhere, I've found references to this linking being done in Configuration => Facets => Edit a facet => Advanced Settings. However, I don't see any option to use a custom facet here, even after I installed the above example facet module to test this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer. Once you create a custom facet module that has the required annotation above the class and enable the module, then you will see the annotation's label in Configuration => Facets => edit a facet => Facet Settings with a checkbox to link this processor to your facet. For example, "Hide start with some letter" will appear in the Facet settings.